# How to set my ArrayList<integer> equal to a function?

Tags: java

Hello So I am doing the merge sort and I think everything is correct I am just having a hard time with the last two lines of the merge_sort function...
On the second to the last line it says "Integer cannot be resolved to a variable, ArrayList cannot be resolved to a variable, Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to int[]." And the last line says: "Type Mismatch cannot convert from int[] to ArrayList." How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
public static ArrayList<Integer>  merge_sort(ArrayList<Integer> B)
{
    if (B.size() <= 1)
        System.out.println(B);


    int midpoint = B.size()/2;
    ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>(midpoint);
    ArrayList<Integer> right;
    if(B.size() % 2 == 0)
        right = new ArrayList<Integer>(midpoint);
    else
        right = new ArrayList<Integer>(midpoint + 1);

    int[] result = new int[B.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < midpoint; i++)
        left.set(i, B.get(i));



    int x = 0;
    for (int j = midpoint; j < B.size(); j++)
    {
        if(x < right.size())
            right.set(x, B.get(j));
            x++;
    }

    left = merge_sort(left);
    right = merge_sort(right);

    result = merge(left, right);
    return result;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> left, ArrayList<Integer> right)
{
    int lengthResult = left.size() + right.size();
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(lengthResult);
    int indexL = 0;
    int indexR = 0;
    int indexRes = 0;

    while (indexL < left.size() || indexR < right.size())
    {
        if(indexL < left.size() && indexR < right.size())
        {
            if (left.get(indexL) <= right.get(indexR))
            {
                result.set(indexRes, left.get(indexL));
                indexL++;
                indexRes++;
            }
            else
            {
                result.set(indexRes, right.get(indexR));
                indexR++;
                indexRes++;
            }   
        }
        else if (indexL < left.size())
        {
            result.set(indexRes, left.get(indexL));
            indexL++;
            indexRes++;
        }
        else if (indexR < right.size())
        {
            result.set(indexRes, right.get(indexR));
            indexR++;
            indexRes++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
int[] result = new int[B.size()];
```

and change this

```
List<Integer> result = merge(left, right);
```

Comment: So I removed int[] result = new int[B.size()];

And replaced result = merge(left,right); for List<integer> result = merge(left, right); 

but it says: "The type List is ambiguous"

Comment: @David Camacho Be sure that `List` is from `java.util` package (not awt). Check your import declaration.

Comment: nevermind i added the library file import java.util.List;

But now on the last line I of merge_sort(on return result) I get "Type mismatch cannot convert from List<Integer> to ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: Change all your methods to return `List<Integer>` (it's better), or you can just use `ArrayList<Integer> = merge(left, right);`

Comment: Ok so I changed to ArrayList<Integer> = merge(left,right); because changing to List<integer> on the methods gave me errors when I set left and right....
Now there are no errors but when I compile I get these errors
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
 at sort.merge_sort(sort.java:113)
 at sort.main(sort.java:39)

Comment: Try to debug it to check what's wrong with ArrayList indexes. It should be somewhere your ArrayList size less than passing index (or null).

Answer (score 0):

Your result is int[] but the merge() method returns an array list,, try changing result into a list

`result = merge(left, right);`

`result type =int[]`
and  `merge(left, right); returns ArrayList<Integer>`

try `List<Integer> result;` instead of `int[] result;`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in java int and Integer are treated differently, one as a primitive type and the other as a Class. So if you are using Integer, then use it as is throughout.

Hence your code becomes

```
List<Integer> result = merge(left, right);
```

instead of defining `int[] result`